# Make WinSCP Better than NotePad++ Plugin FTP_Synchronize

Tags: ftp, notepad++, synchronization, directory-structure, winscp

Notepad++ FTP_Sync plugin works in this way:
It creates a cache directory (let's say `cacheDir`) and saves each FTP file like this:

```
cacheDir
- user@server.com
-- root
--- public_html
---- any_directory
----- any_file.*

- anotheruser@sameORotherserver.com
-- root
--- public_html
---- any_directory
----- any_file.*

- and so on...
```

Now if we open a file in WinSCP with Notepad++, it creates a temporary directory (something like `scp45214`) in Windows's temporary directory. If I open another file, it creates another new temporary directory (`scpxxxx`). So WinSCP doesn't maintain directory structure of FTP file under Window's temporary directory and also when I close WinSCP, it deletes all temporary (`scpxxxx`) directories...

**Can we make WinSCP setting's work just like Notepad++ FTP_Sync plugin, so it can save and maintain directory structure of FTP file?**

Answer (score 1):

In WinSCP, go to the [*Storage* page of Preferences dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_storage) and check the option *Append remote path to temporary path*.

But this still won't prevent WinSCP from deleting local copies on exit.

Request for this is tracked here:
https://winscp.net/tracker/593

---

Alternatively, consider using the WinSCP feature [*Keep remote directory up to date*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date):

With it, you can work on a local copy of the files and have the changes automatically mirrored on your server.

Comment: actually there are 2 issues, 1- not del temp file, 2- not create temp directory scpxxxx and that's it, it will solve our problem, this is not a big issue, i will have to figure out how to compile winscp src